# How can I set up environmental variables for www-data?

Tags: apache-httpd, environment-variables

I asked a [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61258/35867) on dba.se about how I can give my Perl CGI script the password it needs to access the MySQL database it needs to query. I have received only one answer but that one suggests I save the password as an environmental variable.

OK, `apache2` runs as `www-data` and according to `/etc/passwd`, the user's `$HOME` is `/var/www`:

```
$ grep www /etc/passwd
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
```

I tried creating `/var/www/.profile` with this line

```
export db_pass="password"
```

And then had my Perl script print `$ENV{"db_pass"}` but that failed, the variable is empty. I checked with `$ENV{PATH}` and that was printed as expected.

So, how can I set an arbitrary environmental variable for this user?

The server is an Ubuntu Server running on a VM (which runs on Windows, not my choice, don't ask).

```
$ apache2 -version
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 16:42:25
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use Apache [environment variable manipulation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html).

So for example:

```
SetEnv db_pass swordfish
```

This can be done in httpd.conf or in .htaccess. You can also set env vars in [Rewrite Rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e) like this:

```
RewriteRule someurl - [E=dbpass:swordfish]
```